# CSS/Image Rollover/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, image, styles

I am unsure how to approach this. I have an image that when you roll over parts of this a word or another picture will pop-out. That I am pretty confident I can do, the one part I am unsure about is can I get those to remain on the picture after rollover or on click? Maybe do some of this with jQuery?

Thanks for the advice

Comment: With what mark-up? What've you tried? What elements do you want the rollover to happen with? What elements do you want to show/keep-shown?

Comment: the basic concept is I have an image with text (the text is actual images also as the text is styled) and when parts of the image is rolled over those words will show and can be clicked to keep them shown. I have not tried this yet, I have planned on using CSS for rollovers using display:none and maybe jquery for keeping the images there (as mentioned in a few post below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery:

`$('.imageClass').click('#linkId').show();`
It should not disappear unless you use the .toggle() or .bind() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.foo').click(function() {
   $('.something').show();
});
```